# GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS not set after find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

Tags: macos, cmake, googletest

I am running CMake 3.20.2 on Mac Catalina.  I have built gtest and installed it on the system with sudo make install. gtest exists in /usr/include. But when I run cmake lines:
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
GTEST_FOUND is true but GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS is not set. Under what circumstances doe GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS either get set or not by the call to find_package?
The [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html) say these should be set as result variables but only one seems to be set.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CmakeLists.txt`, add `include_directories("GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS")`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the OP has found the answer [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22238).
In summary, it is a backward compatibility issue, which seems to happen only on Mac. The `GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable is not set correctly after calling `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)`. If you can edit your `CMakeLists.txt`, the recommended modern way is to use `target_link_libraries(GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main)` instead of `include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.